# Node.js progress indicator feedback

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a question about the progress of sending with Node.js 'request'. I have a Node.js application that acts as a proxy, actually forwarding a body to another server. I want to see the progress of this upload action. Now I am doing this:

```
BROWSER 
   -> UPLOAD TO NODE 
   -> UPLOAD TO 3rd PARTY SERVICE 
   -> RETURN 3rd PARTY RESPONSE TO BROWSER
```

If this is possible, I would log it to check in the console.log how much progress is done. But, would it also be possible to return a

```
res.send(progress)
```

in the mean time, while waiting for the upload to finish and send the client back the upload has succeeded?

```
BROWSER 
   -> UPLOAD TO NODE
   -> UPLOAD TO 3rd PARTY SERVICE 
       -> RETURN progress <- 
       -> RETURN progress <- 
       ...etc.
   -> RETURN 3rd PARTY RESPONSE TO BROWSER
```

This is the upload code (pretty much straightforward).

```
var requestOptions = {
    timeout: 120000,
    url: url, //URL to hit
    method: 'post',
    headers: headers,
    body: payload //Set the body as a string
};


request(requestOptions, function (error, response, body) {
    if (error) {
        res.send(error);
    }
    else {
        //res.sendStatus(response.statusCode);
        console.log("[RETURNING RESPONSE BODY]");
        res.send(body);
    }
});
```

Comment: use `res.write()` to send updates on the request. When the upload is finished use `res.end()`

Answer (score 10):

Your question contains two parts. One is for getting the progress from request, which can be found here: [Upload Progress — Request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12098713/upload-progress-request)

The other part would be notifying the browser of the progress. The HTTP protocol does not let you send multiple responses, so using `res.send(progress)` is not possible.

However, you can keep sending partial responses until it finishes. Writing something to res without closing it is as simple as `res.write("string")`, but accessing the response can be harder: [Accessing partial response using AJAX or WebSockets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7952448/accessing-partial-response-using-ajax-or-websockets)

You also need a way to wrap the body (and also errors) from the backing server so that it can fit as the final partial response.

Another solution would be opening another WebSocket request to track the uploading/downloading process. socket.io is a good library for node for this purpose.

Comment: Thank you. The first link got me to the solution for the first part. So I need to see it as 2 parts, which makes sense.

I shall look into the socket.io.

Comment: This is much better than the rest, only missing the content relevant to the answer from the links.

Answer (score 1):

Solution for first part was in `r.req.connectin.bytesWritten`

```
var r = request(requestOptions, function (error, response, body) {
    clearInterval(q);
    ...
});

var q = setInterval(function () {
    console.log("Uploaded: " + r.req.connection.bytesWritten);
}, 250);
```

Comment: Although the logic you're implementing is correct, this is not a right answer because you're `console.log`ing it on the server. The op wants it in the browser. :)

Comment: Ah, while I was the OP you are somewhat correct. But I state that this would be a solution for the first part of my question. Am I doing this right? :)

Comment: Come on, @Riel IS the OP. And I'm pretty sure that he or she will improve the answer after finding the right way to do server to client progress reports. ;-)

Comment: @Riël I'm trying to get the bytesWritten of the request but I get only the total size of the FormData... I don't know what I'm doing wrong... also tried _bytesDispatched and the same... do you know what could be the problem? I'm uploading a formdata file (binary)