# Get upload progress for Google Drive NodeJS client?

Tags: node.js, google-drive-api, google-api-nodejs-client

After we get the request object from `req = drive.files.insert` how to use it find file upload progress ?

I searched for it in the `req string` by calling it multiple times but to no avail.

```
function uploadFile(){
    var path = untildify("~/workspace/incomplete/aw.jpg");
    var drive = google.drive('v2');

    var req = drive.files.insert({
        resource: {
            title: 'aw.jpg'
        },
        media: {
            body: fs.createReadStream(path)
        },
        auth: oauth2Client
    }, function(err, response) {
        if (err)
            console.log(err);
        // else
        //  console.log(response);
    });

    console.log(req);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how it's done

```
function uploadFile(){
    var path = untildify("~/workspace/a.jpg");
    var drive = google.drive('v2');
    console.log('start upload');
    var req = drive.files.insert({
        resource: {
            title: "a.jpg"
        },
        media: {
            body: fs.createReadStream(path)
        },
        auth: oauth2Client
    }, function(err, response, body) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            console.log('finish upload');
            clearInterval(q);
        }
    });
    var q = setInterval(function () {
         console.log("Uploaded: " + req.req.connection.bytesWritten);
     }, 250);
}
```

Reference : [Node.js progress indicator feedback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32435830/node-js-progress-indicator-feedback) - Answer by Riel

And special thanks to **Ryan Seys** for helping me out.

Answer (score 0):

Every request to the API returns a `request object`, allowing you to track the request's progress or general information about the request. You need to add a handler for a request part received.

Here is the sample code:

```
part.addListener("request", function(received) {
    // Calculate upload progress
    var progress = (stream.bytesReceived / stream.bytesTotal * 100).toFixed(2);
    var mb = (stream.bytesTotal / 1024 / 1024).toFixed(1);

    sys.debug("Uploading " + mb + "mb (" + progress + "%)");
```

You can find the documentation in this [blog](http://www.componentix.com/blog/9/file-uploads-using-nodejs-now-for-real).

Comment: I haven't quite understood how to use your solution in the code i have posted above. Could you please explain further. Thanks