# Google Drive API v3 Request progress bug

Tags: node.js, google-drive-api, google-api-nodejs-client

Hey I found this v2 solution to get upload progress of your file.
[Get upload progress for Google Drive NodeJS client?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35581502/get-upload-progress-for-google-drive-nodejs-client)

Here is my code

```
function real_upload_files(auth) {
var drive = google.drive({ version: 'v3', auth: auth });

    fs.readFile('./test.zip', function(err, content){
        var fileMetadata = {
            'name': 'test.zip',
        };
        var media = {
            mimeType: 'application/zip',
            body: new Buffer(content, 'binary'),
        };
        var req = drive.files.create({
            resource: fileMetadata,
            media: media,
            auth: auth,
            fields: 'id',
        }, function(err, file) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                console.log('File Id: ', file.id);
                clearInterval(q);  
            } 
        }); 

        var q = setInterval(function () {
         console.log("Uploaded: " + req.req.connection.bytesWritten);
        }, 250);

    }); 
}
```

But I only get

Uploaded: 428
Uploaded: 428
Uploaded: 428
Uploaded: 428

as result. Any Idea why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the code above ist just wrong :D However this worked finally for me with windows cmd.

```
function uploadFile_googledrive(auth) {
var drive = google.drive({ version: 'v3', auth: auth });


        var fileMetadata = {
            'name': 'box.box',
            parents: [ folderID ]

        };
        var media = {
            mimeType: 'application/octet-stream',
            body: fs.createReadStream('C:\\Exports\\box.box')
        };
        var req = drive.files.create({
            resource: fileMetadata,
            media: media,
            auth: auth,
            fields: 'id',
        }, function(err, file) {
            if (err) {
                console.log('Error while uploading your Container to Google Drive - Error: ', err);
            } else {
                console.log('Successfull uploaded your Container to Google Drive with ID: ', file.id);
                clearInterval(q);
            } // else
        }); // drive.files.create({


    var q = setInterval(function () {
         console.log("Uploaded: " + req.req.connection.bytesWritten);
     }, 1000);


} // function uploadFile_googledrive() {
```

parents: [ folderID ] for folderID you need to do the list view from the default script from google drive api.