# drive.files.create upload complete callback

Tags: node.js, google-drive-api

I'm using the drive node library to upload files from my node.js app using readstreams. Here's the snippet of the code. I want to write some logic once my app gets the callback that the upload is complete. How do I find out when the upload is complete or failed? The callback to the drive.files.create doesn't seem to be right place. Does createReadStream gives me a callback?

```
var fileMetadata = {
    name: "test.mp4",
    parents: [folder_id]
};

var media = {
    mimeType: mime_type,
    body: fs.createReadStream(fileid) 
};

drive.files.create({
    resource: fileMetadata,
    media: media
}, function(err, file) {
    //continue processing after upload is complete  
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `fs.createReadStream()` will just allow you to open up a readable stream in a very simple manner.

For your concern regarding the progress of upload API, you can just create a function like this to check the progress of your upload:

```
 var req = drive.files.create({
            resource: fileMetadata,
            media: media
        }, function(err, file) {
            //continue processing after upload is complete  
           clearInterval(q);
        });
  var q = setInterval(function () {
         // will check the upload progress from the request
         console.log("Uploaded: " + req.req.connection.bytesWritten);
         }, 250);
```

For more info:

- [How to get upload progress](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client/issues/520)
- [How to get progress status while uploading files to Google Drive using NodeJs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52026500/how-to-get-progress-status-while-uploading-files-to-google-drive-using-nodejs) (check Tanaike's answer)

Comment: If this will help, you can accept my answer. Thanks :)