# How to track upload progress of a multipart/form-data POST request with NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, file-upload, request, multipartform-data

How do I track the upload progress of a multipart/form-data POST request? I am using `request@2.88.2` with `NodeJS v13` and a quick google search led me to [Upload Progress — Request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12098713/upload-progress-request/), the `setInterval()` implementation worked fine for a direct single file upload, but when uploading multiple files with multipart/form-data it just goes from 0 to 100% almost instantly (AKA doesn't work, useless).

I couldn't find any other existing solutions anywhere else on the Internet so I'm asking here at last.
My current code can be found here: https://hastebin.com/uqobihuyab.js

Comment: Did you try with a large file like 1gb ? Maybe you are uploading a file in your fast localhost.

Comment: @JRichardsz you can see in my linked code that im uploading to https://gofile.io, not localhost, the file currently being upload is 665mb large and takes about a minute to upload, since ive already manually counted a full upload time of this file.