# Progress tracker for POST request

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, socket.io, request

Hello I am fairly new to NodeJS and its modules but I was wondering if I can get some help with this, I am trying to create a progress bar for an application but it only returns 100% when it completes,I don't think i'm using piping right either but any help would be greatly appreciated!

I am also transmitting data through a socket as well if that makes a difference.

```
const request = require('request');
const io = require('socket.io')(http)
const fs = require('fs');
var progress = require('progress-stream');

var str = progress({
    time: 1000
});

str.on('progress', function (progress) {
    console.log(Math.round(progress.percentage) + '%');
});


io.on('connection', (socket)=>{
socket.on('fileUploader',()=>{
    let formData = {
            preview_file: fs.createReadStream(filePath};
        request.post({
                url: 'http://httpbin.org/post',
                formData: formData
            }, 
                function optionalCallback(err, httpResponse, body) {
                if (err) {
                    return console.error('upload failed:', err);
                }
                console.log('Upload successful!  Server responded with:', body);
        }).pipe(str);
    })
})
```

Comment: you can use on drain ref : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12098713/upload-progress-request

Comment: Thank you! I will look more into this!

Answer (score 1):

Try using [axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios),
they have onUploadProgress method, which is you can use the "progressEvent" callback from it to get percentage.

The documentation from axios is pretty clear about [this](https://github.com/axios/axios/blob/master/examples/upload/index.html).

Comment: In axios they get the file through an input file tag, what if I already have the file path, how would I append that to FormData?

Comment: yes you can append it into FormData just like this
https://stackoverflow.com/a/43014086/1446163