# Node.js Express - Client-side download bar?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a `Node.js` server using `Express`

```
const socketio      = require('socket.io'),
      http          = require('http'),
      path          = require('path'),
      express       = require('express'),
      app           = express(),
      serv          = require('http').Server(app),
      cors          = require('cors');

var htmlPath = path.join(__dirname, 'client_data');
    
app.use(cors(corsOptions), express.static(htmlPath));
app.get('/', cors(corsOptions), (req, res, next) => {
    res.sendFile(htmlPath + '/index.html');
});
```

Client connects via

```
function init() {
    var url = 'http://192.168.1.5:8080';
    window.open(url, 'theFrame');
}
```

I'm trying to add a `Download Progress Bar` for the client side (also, for server side would be nice) for the files retrieved via Express. Is this possible? Thanks!

Comment: What is the function that fetches the file on the client side?

Comment: @Ender_The_Xenocide
<body onload="init()">
 <iframe id="frame" name="theFrame"></iframe>
</body>

Comment: So is the download just for index.html?

Comment: @Ender_The_Xenocide for the entire 'client_data' folder

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12098713/upload-progress-request) question might help

Comment: @Ender_The_Xenocide neither helped me :/ 1 is for uploading a file, the other is something else entirely

Comment: Sorry, sent wrong link for the second one :/ [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32435830/node-js-progress-indicator-feedback?noredirect=1&lq=1) is what I meant to send

Comment: The same concepts of the file upload works for download too, I can try to write out some examples if you want

Comment: @Ender_The_Xenocide I would really appreciate that :) if it doesn't take too much of your time. I'm not a very well programmer

Comment: I'll try when I have time